# 'style' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, datatables

Im having some issues with datatables.net and internet explorer 8 ( Could also be other browsers, but works in IE9). I have spent some time trying to find out what the issue is and i have been unable, but i have figured out what javascript that seems to trigger it:

If i remove this code then it works in IE 8, can someone point out the error in my ways ?

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sType": "string" },                       // Player name
    { "sType": "numeric-minus" },                       // Damage done
    { "sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false },    // DPS real
    { "sType": "numeric-comma" },                       // DPS Avg
    {"sType": "numeric-minus" },                        // Damage taken
    {"sType": "numeric-minus" },                        // Healing done
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false },    // healing done HPS
    {"sType": "numeric-comma" },    // healing done HPS Avg
    { "sType": "numeric-comma" },                       // Overhealing
    { "sType": "numeric-comma" },                       // Healing taken
    { "sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false },    // Mana done
    { "sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false },    // Stamina done
    {"sType": "string", "bVisible": false },            // Class
    {"sType": "percent" },                              // Activity
],
```

**Error details from IE 8**

    Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 28 Jul 2011 09:59:45 UTC    

Message: 'style' is null or not an object
Line: 5585
Char: 7
Code: 0
media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
```

Lines from datatable around error ( Error line has comment behind it ).

> Function: _fnGetUniqueThs Purpose:  Get an array of unique th
>   elements, one for each column
>  Returns:  array node:aReturn - list
>   of unique ths
>  Inputs:   object:oSettings - dataTables settings
>   object
>  node:nHeader - automatically detect the layout from this
>   node - optional
>  array object:aLayout - thead/tfoot layout from
>   _fnDetectHeader - optional

```
var nThs = _fnGetUniqueThs( oSettings, nTheadClone );
iCorrector = 0;
for ( i=0 ; i<iColums ; i++ )
{
    var oColumn = oSettings.aoColumns[i];
    if ( oColumn.bVisible && oColumn.sWidthOrig !== null && oColumn.sWidthOrig !== "" )
    {
        nThs[i-iCorrector].style.width = _fnStringToCss( oColumn.sWidthOrig );
    }
    else if ( oColumn.bVisible )
    {
        nThs[i-iCorrector].style.width = ""; // This is the error line
    }
    else
    {
        iCorrector++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post here line 5585 in the file `media/js/jquery.dataTables.js`?

Comment: Error seems releated to width, i have automatic width ( IE i dont spesify width of colums

Comment: Added definition of nThs

Comment: @EKS: What does the function `_fnGetUniqueThs` return?

Comment: Added description on that function.

Comment: Remove the trailing comma: `[1,2,].length // Firefox: 2 | IE: 3`

Comment: @Saxoier: thanks, you saved me going mad. Is there a tool that can help in finding these kind of syntatic incompatibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code fixed the problem for me, il leave the question open perhaps somone knows why it works with this change.

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sType": "string", "sWidth": "auto" },                       // Player name
    {"sType": "numeric-minus", "sWidth": "auto" },                       // Damage done
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "auto" },    // DPS real
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "sWidth": "auto" },                       // DPS Avg
    {"sType": "numeric-minus", "sWidth": "auto" },                        // Damage taken
    {"sType": "numeric-minus", "sWidth": "auto" },                        // Healing done
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "auto" },    // healing done HPS
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "sWidth": "auto" },    // healing done HPS Avg
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "sWidth": "auto" },                       // Overhealing
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "sWidth": "auto" },                       // Healing taken
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "auto" },    // Mana done
    {"sType": "numeric-comma", "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "auto" },    // Stamina done
    {"sType": "string", "bVisible": false, "sWidth": "auto" },            // Class
    {"sType": "percent", "sWidth": "auto" }                              // Activity
],
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is most likely your last object in the aoColumns array:

```
    {"sType": "percent" },   
],
```

You've left the comma on the last entry. I made the same error and it worked happily with Firefox at least, but not IE 8.

Comment: this s a rather primitive regex to find these bad-asses },[^\]|}]*\]

Comment: It was the trailing comma that was causing issues for me in IE8 and this fixed it.

Comment: yup. IE8 not like modern browsers can't take care of extra commas. removing the last comma after the last column will fix it for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

in my case using `width="100%"` in table caused the problem, removing width solved it.

**working code**

```
<table id="dt_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>column1</th>
    <th>column2</th>
    <th>column3</th>
    <th>column4</th>
    <th>column5</th>
    <th>column6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```